# Null Pointer Exception because memberCache is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am not asking what is null pointer exception here.I have debugged the project and saw where my null pointer is coming.My flow for project is:

[image]

My Api is:

```
package com.cache.api;

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource  {

    @Inject
    private CacheHelper cacheHelper;

    @Inject
    private DtoPlan dtoPlan;

    @GET
    @Path("/putAllInDto")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String putAllInDto() throws Exception {

       CachePlan cf=CacheFactory.getPlan(PlanChooser.DTO);
       cf.putInCache(); //data are loaded in DtoPlanImpl Class

        MemberDTO md=cf.getMemberDtos();  //data comes from here with cf object

    //    MemberDTO md1=dtoPlan.getMemberDto();  //java.lang.NullPointerException when I use dtoPlan.memberDto();

//
//        System.out.println(md.getMemberName());
        return "insertedindto";
    }


}
```

The cachePlan interface is:

```
package com.cache.plan;

    public interface CachePlan {

        public  void putInCache() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException ;

        public MemberDTO getMemberDtos() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException ;

        }
```

My DtoPlanImpl.java class is.Here I needed to implement new interface **DtoPlan**.

```
package com.cache.impl;


    @Stateless
    public class DtoPlanImpl implements CachePlan,DtoPlan
    {

        private CacheManager cacheManager;

        private Cache<String,MemberDTO> memberCache;

        private static final String CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER="cache_member_dto_type";

        private MemberService memberService = CDI.current().select(MemberService.class).get();


        public DtoPlanImpl(){
            System.getProperties().setProperty("java -Dnet.sf.ehcache.use.classic.lru", "true");
            cacheManager= CacheManagerBuilder
                    .newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
            cacheManager.init();
        }


        @Override
        public void putInCache()  {
            System.out.println("putting data from dto");

            memberCache = cacheManager
                    .createCache("cacheOfMemberCache", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                            .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                    String.class,MemberDTO.class,
                                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000000000)).withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration
                                    (Duration.of(60000,
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS))));

            memberCache.put(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER,memberService.getMemberDTO());

            MemberDTO mD=memberCache.get(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER);
            System.out.println(mD.getMemberName());

         }

        @Override
        public MemberDTO getMemberDtos() {
            MemberDTO mD=memberCache.get(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER);
            return mD;
        }


        @Override
        public MemberDTO getMemberDto() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            MemberDTO mD=memberCache.get(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER);
             return mD;
        }


    }
```

My DtoPlan interface is:

```
public interface DtoPlan {

    public MemberDTO getMemberDto() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException;


}
```

So what is the problem is that when i use CacheFactory cf as:

```
MemberDTO md=cf.getMemberDtos();  //data comes from here with cf object
```

But when I use:

```
 MemberDTO md1=dtoPlan.getMemberDto();  //java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I debugged the program and visualized from where the null pointer excpetion is coming:
Its coming from this Class DtoPlanImpl at line  `MemberDTO mD=memberCache.get(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER);`:

```
@Override
    public MemberDTO getMemberDto() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        MemberDTO mD=memberCache.get(CACHE_MEMBER_DTO_PARAMETER);
         return mD;
    }
```

The memberCache is being null here where I call from `dtoPlan.getMemberDto();`, but when I call from `cf.getMemberDtos();`,I am getting data.

Comment: Is `dtoPlan` being injected? If so, how? A NPE at `MemberDTO md1=dtoPlan.getMemberDto()` can only occur if `dtoPlan` is `null`! This means that this question does qualify as a duplicate of [what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes i debugged and saw dtoPlan Proxy for view class: com.cache.plan.DtoPlan of EJB: DtoPlanImpl
constructed:true
  methodHandler={ProxyMethodHandler}

Comment: If that is the case, your NPE is not really coming from this call: `dtoPlan.getMemberDto()` -

Comment: but this also appeared dtoPlan=Cannot find local variable 'dtoPlan'

Comment: Your code does not show a local variable `dtoPlan`.

Comment: its being injected or not I am not sure

Comment: `@Inject` is just a specification. There needs to be a provider of dependency injection so that the injection works.

Comment: yes i have used CDI,and provided the beans configuration.The @Inject is working fine for other interface.

Comment: its being injected but my memberCache is getting null when i debugged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `memberCache` in `putInCache()` method instead of initializing in constructor. With your design, you need to put something in the cache before you can retrieve something. So either initialize it in the constructor or *put* something in it.

Also note that by default Guice returns a new instance each time it supplies a value. So you may be using one instance while putting stuff into the cache, hence initializing `memberCache`, but using another instance while retrieving data, in which `memberCache` is null. You can use [`@Singleton`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) annotation to inject the same instance of `DtoPlan` everywhere.

And looks like you are creating a new instance of cache every time you need to put something in it. So you lose the previously stored values. This whole code looks flawed.

Comment: where should i use singleton annotation? can u please show me ?

Comment: i just need to instantiate cache once,if i put in constructor it will be initialized every time when i will make the object or refresh the web page

Comment: That's why you need singleton dependency injection. You can put that annotation on `DtoPlanImpl` class. But it's highly likely that you'll still face issues. You'll need to fix your `putInCache` method and constructor and maybe other things. I think this question is too broad. You should read more about Java.

Comment: yes you were right i put the membercache in constructor and NPE has gone,but my cache needs to only initialize once,I am getting problem there,when I will put inside contructor,then if I hit the api for 100 times then cache will load data for 100 times.